# The output of a subroutine is returning 0

Tags: perl

I have written a script which uses a subroutine to call percentage of nucleotides in a given sequence. When I run the script the output for each nucleotide percentage is always shown to be zero.

Here's my code;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#### Subroutine to report percentage of each nucleotide in DNA sequence ####

my $input = $ARGV[0];
my $nt = $ARGV[1];
my $args = $#ARGV +1;

if($args != 2){
    print "Error!!! Insufficient number of arguments\n";
    print "Usage: $0 <input fasta file>\n";
}

my($FH, $line);

open($FH, '<', $input) || die "Could\'nt open file: $input\n";

$line = do{
    local $/;
    <$FH>;
};

$line =~ s/>(.*)//g;
$line =~ s/\s+//g;

my $perc = perc_nucleotide($line , $nt);
printf("The percentage of $nt nucleotide in given sequence is %.0f", $perc);
print "\n";


sub perc_nucleotide {
    my($line, $nt) = @_;
    print "$nt\n";
    my $count = 0;
    if( $nt eq "A" || $nt eq "T" || $nt eq "G" || $nt eq "C"){
    $count++;
    }
    my $total_len = length($line);
    my $perc = ($count/$total_len)*100;

}
```

I think that I am setting the `$count` variable wrong. I tried different ways but can't figure it out.

This is the input file

```
>XM_024894547.1 Trichoderma citrinoviride Redoxin (BBK36DRAFT_1163529), partial mRNA
ATGGCCTTCCGTCTCCCTCTGCGCCGCATTGCCCTGGCCCGCCCCGCCACCGTTGCGCGTGGCTTCCACT
CGACGCCCCGCGCCCTGGTCAAGGTCGGCGACGAGGTCCCGAGCTTGGAGCTGTTCGAGAAGTCGGCCGC
CAGCAAGATCAACCTGGCCGACGAGTTCAAGAAGGGCGACGGCTACATTGTCGGCGTCCCGGGCGCCTTC
TCCGGCACCTGCTCCGGCACCCACGTCCCGTCGTACATCAACCACCCTGACATCAAGACGGCCGGCCAGG
TCTTTGTCGTCTCCGTCAACGACCCCTTTGTCATGAAGGCTTGGGCAGACCAGCTGGATCCCGCCGGAGA
GACAGGAATCCGGTTCGTTGCCGACCCCACGGCTGAGTTCACAAAGGCTCTGGAACTGGGATTCGACGAC
GCTGCTCCTCTGTTCGGAGGCACCCGAAGCAAGCGCTATGCTCTCAAGGTTAAGGATGGCAAGGTCACTG
CCGCCTTTGTTGAGCCCGACAACACGGGCACTTCCGTGTCAATGGCCGACAAGGTCCTCAGCTAA
```

Comment: How are you executing the script? What arguments are you passing?

Comment: ./script.pl nucleotide.fasta A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
my $perc = perc_nucleotide($line , $nt);
printf("The percentage of $nt nucleotide in given sequence is %.0f", $perc);
```

`perc_nucleotide` is returning `0.18018018018018` but the format `%.0f` says to print it with no decimal places. So it gets truncated to 0. You should probably use something more like `%.2f`.

---

It's also worth noting that `perc_nucleotide` does not have a `return`. It still works, but for reasons that might not be obvious.

`perc_nucleotide` sets `my $perc = ($count/$total_len)*100;` but never uses that `$perc`. The `$perc` in the main program is a different variable.

`perc_nucleotide` does return something, every Perl subroutine without an explicit return returns the "last evaluated expression". In this case it's  `my $perc = ($count/$total_len)*100;` but the last evaluated expression rules can get a bit tricky.

It's easier to read and safer to have an explicit return. `return ($count/$total_len)*100;`

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the script and it gave me right answers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

##### Subroutine to calculate percentage of all nucleotides in a DNA sequence #####

my $input = $ARGV[0];
my $nt = $ARGV[1];
my $args = $#ARGV + 1;

if($args != 2){
    print "Error!!! Insufficient number of arguments\n";
    print "Usage: $0 <input_fasta_file> <nucleotide>\n";
}

my($FH, $line);

open($FH, '<', $input) || die "Couldn\'t open input file: $input\n";

$line = do{
    local $/;
    <$FH>;
};

chomp $line;

#print $line;

$line =~ s/>(.*)//g;
$line =~ s/\s+//g;

#print "$line\n";

my $total_len = length($line);
my $perc_of_nt = perc($line, $nt);

**printf("The percentage of nucleotide $nt in a given sequence is %.2f%%", $perc_of_nt);
print "\n";**


#print "$total_len\n";

sub perc{
    my($line, $nt) = @_;
    my $char; my $count = 0;
    **foreach $char (split //, $line){
    if($char eq $nt){
        $count += 1;
    }
    }** 
**return (($count/$total_len)*100)**
}
```

The answer for the above input file is:

```
Total_len = 555
The percentage of nucleotide A in a given sequence is 18.02%
The percentage of nucleotide T in a given sequence is 18.74%
The percentage of nucleotide G in a given sequence is 28.47%
```

The changes which I made are in bold.

Thanks for amazing insight!!!